# Why are my images being set to UIImageOrientationRight when taken on an iPod running iOS 6 in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

My setup is this for testing is this:

- iPod Touch 4th Generation (non-autofocus camera)
- Running iOS 6.1.6 (latest for this model)
- App is built with latest Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7.1, but with backwards compatibility to run on iOS 6 devices

Whenever I take a portrait picture with this device using `UIImagePickerController`, my returning image has an orientation of `UIImageOrientationRight`. Shouldn't it be giving me `UIImageOrientationUp`?

Here is the call I use to open the camera:

```
- (IBAction)goToCamera
{
    UIImagePickerController *mypicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mypicker.delegate = self;
    mypicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    mypicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    mypicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    mypicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [self presentViewController:mypicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here is the return delegate call:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"%d", pickedImage.imageOrientation);
}
```

The NSLog is always showing `UIImageOrientationRight`, even when I take the picture in portrait. Why?

Comment: Is it still `UIImageOrientationRight` when you take it in landscape?

Comment: No, strangely enough, when I take the picture in landscape the orientation is `UIImageOrientationUp`. What could be going on here? How could the app think it's in a different orientation?

Comment: It doesn't; the camera's "top" is actually one of the sides of the device.

Answer (score 1):

Image Orientation is not the same as Interface Orientation.

As you've discovered, the camera's native orientation is landscape (makes sense, that's the "expected" orientation of traditional cameras)  Rather than go to the expense of actually rotating images taken in other orientations, iOS just changes the orientation tag so that it will get displayed correctly.

Comment: ah OK I see... so when rotated that is `UIImageOrientationUp`. Thanks for the clarification.